# How to call a longlistselector event from an option in context menu

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, contextmenu, longlistselector

```
private void Deleting(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBoxResult message = MessageBox.Show(
        "The file will be permanently deleted. Continue?",
        "Delete File", 
        MessageBoxButton.OKCancel
    );

    if (message == MessageBoxResult.OK)
    {   
        LongListSelector selector = sender as LongListSelector;

        SoundData data1 = selector.SelectedItem as SoundData;

       //control goes inside this block
        if (selector == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (data1 == null)
            return;
    }
}
```

I must be able to access that data from the long list selector. The deleting event handler is from context menu button

This code was able to reference the option in longlistselector. Thanks to Venkatapathi Raju for help

```
      public void Deleting(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        SoundData data1 = (sender as MenuItem).DataContext as SoundData;

        MessageBoxResult message = MessageBox.Show(
        "The file will be permanently deleted. Continue?",
        "Delete File",
        MessageBoxButton.OKCancel
        );

        if (message == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
```

private void LongListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            LongListSelector selector = sender as LongListSelector;

```
        if (selector == null)
            return;

        SoundData data = selector.SelectedItem as SoundData;

        if (data == null)
            return;

        if (File.Exists(data.FilePath))
        {
            AudioPlayer.Source = new Uri(data.FilePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        }
        else
        {
            using (var storageFolder = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                //Breakpoint 
         using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(data.FilePath, FileMode.Open, storageFolder))
                 {
                    AudioPlayer.SetSource(stream);
                }
            }
        }
```

And I get this error message 
An exception of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you. The `DataContext` property of the contextmenu gives you the `longlistselector`'s `menuItem`.

You can perform the delete operation as shown below:

```
private void Deleting(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SoundData data1 = (sender as MenuItem).DataContext as SoundData;

    MessageBoxResult message = MessageBox.Show(
    "The file will be permanently deleted. Continue?",
    "Delete File", 
    MessageBoxButton.OKCancel
    );

    if (message == MessageBoxResult.OK)
    {   
        //Call the method which deletes the data and pass data1 to it.
    }
}
```

I believe you are learning from Bob Tabor's videos. Keep it going.

```
private void Delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        SoundData data = (sender as MenuItem).DataContext as SoundData;
        MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to delete this item ?", "Are you sure ?", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

        if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            if (data == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The file doesn't exist");
                return;
            }

            using (var storageFolder = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (storageFolder.FileExists(data.FilePath))
                {
                    storageFolder.DeleteFile(data.FilePath);

                    App.ViewModel.CustomSounds.Items.Remove(data);

                    // Save the list of CustomSounds to IsolatedStorage.ApplicationSettings
                    var JsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(App.ViewModel.CustomSounds);

                    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[SoundModel.CustomSoundKey] = JsonData;
                    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();

                    App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded = false;
                    App.ViewModel.LoadData();

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("File doesn't exist");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Yeah I am following Bob Tabor's Videos. IsolatedStorageFile isofile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                isofile.DeleteFile(data1.FilePath);
                isofile.DeleteFile(data1.Title);            
                App.ViewModel.CustomSounds.Items.Remove(data1); This deletes my isolated storage file but the button remains in the page. Why is it not getting removed?

Comment: Try adding `App.ViewModel.LoadData();` after the line `App.ViewModel.CustomSounds.Items.Remove(data1);`

Accept the answer if it works for you so that other's wont have to look over this question as unanswered.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah I mentioned in front. Is there anyway to set the question as "resolved" something like that. I am new to stackoverflow and windowsphoneapp development. Meantime, adding App.ViewModel.LoadData(); does not work for me. It is still in the list. When I click it the control goes out of the app.

Comment: If it is still in the list, what happens when you tap it after deleting ? And you can set it to resolved by clicking on the tick mark below the correct answer.

Comment: longlistselector selectionchanged eventhandler:   if (File.Exists(data.FilePath))
            {
                AudioPlayer.Source = new Uri(data.FilePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            }
            else
            {
                using (var storageFolder = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())//Breakpoint
                {
                    using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(data.FilePath, FileMode.Open, storageFolder))
                    {
                        AudioPlayer.SetSource(stream);
                    }
                }
            }

Comment: What I asked is, is it throwing any exception when you tap on the longlist item after it is deleted ? Or it simply does nothing ? 

Try to put a breakpoint and see what is the value of `data` that is already deleted but when you tap on it again.

Comment: Yeah I added in my question along with the break point and the exception that I get

Comment: When I give longlistselectorname.updatelayout(); it gets removed in the app. But when I open the application again, it pops up

Comment: Thank you very much Venkatapathi Raju

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it:

```
private void Deleting(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBoxResult message = MessageBox.Show(
        "The file will be permanently deleted. Continue?",
        "Delete File", 
        MessageBoxButton.OKCancel
    );

    if (message == MessageBoxResult.OK)
    {                  
        SoundData data1 = myLongListSelector.SelectedItem as SoundData;

        if (data1 == null)
            return;

       //control goes inside this block  
    }
}
```

Also remember to set selectoed item to null (at the end of method) as it's deleted:

```
myLongListSelector.SelectedItem = null;
```

Comment: Thank you Romasz. Its helpful